# Symfony, doctrine Removing Associations setEntity(null) not allowed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to remove the association between two objects with the following relation

Devis Entity :

```
class Devis
{
 /**
 * @var \stdClass
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DevisBundle\Entity\Client", inversedBy="devis", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, nullable=true)
 */
private $client;
/**
 * Set client
 *
 * @param \DevisBundle\Entity\Client $client
 * @return Devis
 */

public function setClient(\DevisBundle\Entity\Client $client)
{
    $this->client = $client;

    return $this;
}
```

Client entity:

```
class Client
{
 /**
 * @var \stdClass
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DevisBundle\Entity\Devis", mappedBy="client", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $devis;
```

I tried to folllow the doc from doctrine : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#removing-associations

```
    $devis = $em->getRepository('DevisBundle:Devis')->findOneById($devisId);
    $client = $em->getRepository('DevisBundle:Client')->findOneById($devis->getClient());

    $client->getDevis()->removeElement($devis);
    $devis->setClient(null);

    //$em->persist($devis);
    $em->flush();
    dump($devis);
```

But I have this error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to DevisBundle\Entity\Devis::setClient() must be an instance of DevisBundle\Entity\Client, null given, called in....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your set Method like this :

```
public function setClient(\DevisBundle\Entity\Client $client = null)
{
    $this->client = $client;

    return $this;
}
```

This is also how it would be generated with the command doctrine:generate:entities.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't understand why i did not have $client = null in my setter, I generated this setter with the command doctrine:generate:entities...

Comment: Was your property annotation with 'nullable = true' the first time you generated it ?

Comment: setters are only created once, if you generate entities again it would only add the setters and getters that no exist.

Comment: I can't remember, I generated this setter a long time ago. Anyway I will remember this next time.